# ¿Por qué al cargar un archivo txt con 20 registros a MySQL sí funciona pero con un archivo de 1K+ no? C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo una aplicación en C# donde se arrastra un archivo `.txt` a un panel. Al presionar un botón, el contenido de este archivo se debe pasar a una base de datos `Mysql`.

El contenido del archivo son campos de una tabla delimitados por el caracter `~`, donde selecciono columnas específicas para mandar a un insert de `Mysql`. El formato del contenido del archivo es como el siguiente ejemplo:

Clave1~Clave2~Texto~Texto~Clave3~Texto

000~000~Mi grandiosa aplicación~Hola~000~Hola

Tengo que alimentar cuatro tablas con este archivo. Para ello, tengo métodos como el siguiente, por cada tabla que deseo alimentar:

```
public static void cargarMaterias(FileInfo informacionArchivo)
    {
        List<Materia> listaMaterias = new List<Materia>();
        archivo = new System.IO.StreamReader(informacionArchivo.FullName);

        while (((linea = archivo.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            try
            {
                Materia materia = new Materia();
                b = linea.Split('~');

                materia.ClaveMateria = b[1];
                materia.NombreMateria = b[2];
                materia.Tipo = b[8];
                materia.HorasSemana = 4;
                materia.Actividad = 1;

                DAOMateria.crear(materia);
                listaMaterias.Add(materia);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        archivo.Close();
    }

public static void cargarMaestros(FileInfo informacionArchivo)
    {
        List<Maestro> listaMaestros = new List<Maestro>();
        archivo = new System.IO.StreamReader(informacionArchivo.FullName);

        while ((linea = archivo.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Maestro maestro = new Maestro();
                b = linea.Split('~');

                maestro.NoMaestro = Int32.Parse(b[4]);
                maestro.NombreMaestro = b[5];

                DAOMaestro.crear(maestro);
                listaMaestros.Add(maestro);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
        archivo.Close();
    }
```

Mis tablas deben borrarse cada vez antes de volverlas alimentar. Para eso, tengo este método que manda a llamar los anteriores:

```
 public static void cargarGrupos(FileInfo informacionArchivo)
        {
            DAOMateriaGrupoHorario.borrarMateriasGrupo();
            DAOMateriaGrupo.borrarMateriasGrupo();
            DAOMaestro.borrarMaestros();
            DAOMateria.borrarMaterias();
            cargarMaterias(informacionArchivo);
            cargarMaestros(informacionArchivo);
            cargarMateriasGrupo(informacionArchivo);
            cargarMateriasGruposHorario(informacionArchivo);
        }
```

Anexo aquí el código que tengo para la inserción de registros a la base de datos:

```
public static void crear(Materia materia)
    {
        String instruccionSQL =
               $@"INSERT INTO 
                    materias (claveMateria, nombreMateria, tipo, horasSemana, actividad) 
                  VALUES (
                        @claveMateria, 
                        @nombreMateria, 
                        @tipo, 
                        @horasSemana, 
                        @actividad
                    );";

        MySqlCommand consulta = ejecutarConsulta(instruccionSQL);
        asignarParametros(consulta, materia);
        consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

public static void asignarParametros(MySqlCommand consulta, Materia materia)
        {
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claveMateria", materia.ClaveMateria);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreMateria", materia.NombreMateria);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", materia.Tipo);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horasSemana", materia.HorasSemana);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actividad", materia.Actividad);
        }

public static MySqlCommand ejecutarConsulta(string sentenciaSQL)
        {
            using (MySqlTransaction transaccion = ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand consulta = new MySqlCommand(sentenciaSQL, ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion);
                    transaccion.Commit();
                    return consulta;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw (ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Y aquí la clase donde manejo la conexión mediante un singleton:

```
class ConexionBDSingleton
{
    private static MySqlConnection instancia = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private ConexionBDSingleton() { }

    public static MySqlConnection Conexion
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instancia == null)
                {
                    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IngenieriaDB"].ToString());
                    conexion.Open();
                    return conexion;
                }
                return instancia;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que si subo un archivo `.txt` de prueba con 20 líneas, el programa responde bien, se carga en la base de datos la información que deben tener esas cuatro tablas. Sin embargo, cuando cargo un archivo real, con más de 1K de líneas, la aplicación se queda congelada. Me alimenta sólo la primera tabla, pero entre más reduzco la cantidad de líneas del archivo de texto, me va alimentando las otras tablas, de forma gradual. Con 25 líneas, mi aplicación funciona correctamente. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a saber qué es lo que está pasando? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que tal si en un solo método lees el archivo, haces la separación y cargas las listas de objetos? En los ejemplos que proporcionaste, podrías crear los objetos Materia y Maestro y añadirlos en sus listas correspondientes en un mismo bloque de código.

Comment: Ya lo intenté. Mi aplicación se congela igual, pero no me insertan todos los datos que debería.

Comment: ¿Si solo pruebas cargar materias  del archivo de 1000 lineas si lo carga bien? ¿Podrías incluir el código del método  DAOMateria.crear(materia)?

Comment: ¿Has revisado si estás cerrando las conexiones a la base de datos?, se me ocurre que, cuando tienes pocas lineas que guardar todo funciona bien, sin embargo, con muchas lineas si no cierras las conexiones a la base de datos, estas se quedarán abiertas y llegarás al límite máximo de conexiones de MySql y entonces no se podrán abrir nuevas conexiones.

Comment: Podes mostrar como mandas los datos a la base de datos?

Comment: @JYass No, no lo carga bien. Como que se quedan truncados los registros de materias y de allí en adelante los demás.

Comment: Ya he agregado el código de la conexión a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Qué sucede si colocas un breakpoint en el catch del método cargarMaestros? Es posible que esté generando una excepción pero como no hay código para manejarlo, aparentemente no sucede nada.

Comment: @JYass He colocado en el catch de cargarMaestros y cargarMaterias la línea: `Console.WriteLine($"Materia duplicada: {ex.ToString()}");`. Esto me inserta todos los datos, sin embargo, dura mucho en hacer las inserciones (como dos minutos por tabla). Sin embargo, al continuar con la tercera, me marca una exepción de conexión timed out.

Comment: @JYass por otro lado, si no imprimo la excepción y pongo cualquier otra cosa me sucede que se insertan 400 líneas del archivo; depsués de 15 segundos, me inserta la 401, otros 15 segundos y así sucesivamente. Sin embargo, a veces sí me inserta todos los registros, a veces no lo hace, o eso que comenté antes, sucede en la línea 250, 360... En un número muy variable.

Answer (score 0):

¡Al fin supe qué era!

Si ponía en el `catch` que me imprimiera la excepción generada mediante: `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` para todos los métodos que insertaban en la base de datos, al llenar la penúltima tabla me apareció un error que decía:

`The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool`

Busqué este error y, luego de probar algunas cosas, tuve que cambiar mi acceso a la conexión del DAOMateria, DAOMaestro, etcétera, quedando mi conexión así:

```
public static MySqlCommand ejecutarConsulta(string sentenciaSQL)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand consulta = new MySqlCommand(sentenciaSQL, ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion))
        {
            ConexionBDSingleton.Conexion.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
            return consulta;
        }
    }
```

Y el método para leer el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void cargarMaterias(FileInfo informacionArchivo)
    {
        List<Materia> listaMaterias = new List<Materia>();
        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(informacionArchivo.FullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader lectura = new StreamReader(archivo);
        contador = 1;

        while (((linea = lectura.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            try
            {
                Materia materia = new Materia();
                b = linea.Split('~');

                materia.ClaveMateria = b[1];
                materia.NombreMateria = b[2];
                materia.Tipo = b[8];
                materia.HorasSemana = 4;
                materia.Actividad = 1;
                DAOMateria.crear(materia);
                listaMaterias.Add(materia);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Materia duplicada");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Línea No. {contador}");
            contador++;
            archivo.Flush();
        }
        archivo.Close();
        lectura.Close();
    }
```

Básicamente, tenía que limpiar el pool de conexiones. 
¡Gracias!